# Quickest way to access large set of lat/lon data

Tags: javascript

I have a large amount of data that is indexed by lat/lon to 5 decimal places. I am trying to show this data on a map, but only want to show the lats/lons within the current view, which will only be about 10% of the entire database. I currently have the database stored in an array, i.e. db[0], db[1], db[2], db[3]..... db[3000]. Each item in the array is a { name: value, name2: value2, etc } symbolizer with variables. Every time I work with the data I have to parse the entire array, then filter for lat/lon, then do the operations on the data. To me this seems very client processor intensive and I was wondering if there could be a more efficient way to store the data into the array and access it, maybe: db[lat][tenths][hundredths][thousandths][etc]. Then when I reference it, call it like this: db[29][1][2]. This sounds good, but I'm not sure how to do it. Anyone know how? THANKS!

Comment: Some databases have geo features, so you could search by lat/lon columns efficiently. What about searching in given range that could make sql query make a bit faster ? You can`t complain as you don`t have normalized data - why do you have array in DB row ?!

Comment: Do you have an actual DBS, or do you mean "array with data" if you say "database"? And yes, some kind of 2D range tree would certainly help.

Comment: Well the data is stored in the server using MySql, but the operations on the data are client side. I get the data to the client using AJAX and JSON, then I parse the JSON string into an array full of symbolizers. I'm hoping that when I parse the JSON string, I can put it into the array in a different way that allows me to access the data by lat/lon blocks quicker. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing the data in a datastore which supports geo-spacial data and queries natively? [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/) would be one such option, and stores data in a JSON format.

If you want to do this entirely in the client, then you might find it useful to implement something [like what's described here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), though it likely won't be much quicker.